# Execute SQL Task fails in SSIS 2008 package but runs successfully outside package

Tags: sql, ssis

I created an execute sql task to save the filenames encountered in a Foreach Loop task into a database table,
this works fine when I run the the individual task and it writes the filename to the database table (see below)
UNABLE TO POST IMAGES CURRENTLY
![task successfully runs][1]
However when i run the complete SSIS package, this task fails (see below)
UNABLE TO POST IMAGES CURRENTLY

![unsuccessful execution][2]
The error message I am getting is:

```
Error: String or binary data would be truncated.
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "insert into filename_staging_table
(FileName) Val..." failed with the following error: 
"The statement has been terminated.". Possible
failure reasons: Problems with the query,
"ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters
not set correctly,
or connection not established correctly.
```

Any guidance with this greatly appreciated....I am completely stuck!!!!

Thanks

Comment: While you can't use the integrated image option until your reputation level is higher, manually post them to an location and then link them here. It will make understanding your package design much easier.

Comment: Is the SSIS package running under your credentials? Perhaps it could be a security issue.

Comment: Sounds like your insert is trying to cram too wide a data entry into a column. Can you verify that all the columns being inserted have values that fall within the maximum widths in the table?

Comment: Please post the structure of the table you are saving file names into and your insert statement/stored procedure call. Could it be that your intention is to only store a file name `foo.bar` but you actually writing `C:\folder1\folder2\foo.bar` and that's overflowing your column length?

Comment: You say you are running in a loop - is one of the values you are trying to enter within your loop longer than the datatype of the underlying column?

Answer (score 1):

The error reads "String or binary data would be truncated." The reason the script works when run manualy is because you are only trying to insert one value. That value is within the length constraint of your column.

When you run the task, it is looping through a list of filenames and trying to insert each one. One of these names is too long for the field you are trying to insert it into.

You need to change the length of the field in SQL or you need to use a LEFT(filename, xx) on the filename itself so that a only the first xx characters are inserted into your table. (Change the xx to the number of characters to be inserted)